# How to override d3.js's limit on number of elements that can be rendered?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, data-visualization

I am trying to create a visualization in d3.js, with 4 scatter plots (think a 2x2 matrix plot) and ~1000 data points in total. Each plot should have its own set of axes and include the 1:1 line and a linear fit line. This is all happening in one svg.

It seems that my browser (chrome) can't render more than a couple hundred of data points. Is there a way to override this limit?

**EDIT:** Here is a sample of what I'm doing with dummy data. Clearly, the data points in the first quadrant are not being plotted.

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(two)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d){
                return (w + xscale(d[0]));
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d){
                return yscale(d[1]);
            })
            .attr("r", 2);
```

I basically used the same code for the first and second graphs, but added a w to cx, as shown above.

Comment: d3 shouldn't have a problem plotting 1,000+ points on chrome; you might want to post a link to what you have so far.

Comment: Thanks @AdamPearce, I just posted a link to a jsfiddle with some dummy data. The idea here is to create a scatter plot for 4 different series, each one will have around ~300 data points. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The svg.selectAll("circle") calls are interfering with each other. You need to differentiate your groups of circles; for example, by adding a class to each:

```
svg.selectAll("circle.one")
  .data(one)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class","one")
  .attr("cx", function(d){
    return xscale(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d){
    return yscale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("r", 2);
```

...

```
svg.selectAll("circle.two")
  .data(two)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class","two")
  .attr("cx", function(d){
    return (w + padding + xscale(d[0]));
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d){
    return yscale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("r", 2);
```

(Also, note that I added padding to the "two" group's x value.)

Here's your example, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/pzp4h/3/

Comment: @avyfain No problem! I've been struggling with some similar D3 issues lately. If this solution worked for you, would you mind accepting it as the correct answer? (My rep needs all the help it can get.)